# 'PFUser' does not have a member named 'subscript'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I don't have enough reputation to post the images,
I'm using Parse to signup and it shows me 'PFUser' does not have a member named 'subscript' error

Please check the code below

```
var user = PFUser()
    user.username = usernameTextField.text
    user.email = emailTextField.text
    user.password = passwordTextField.text

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImage.image)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name: "profilePhoto.png", data: imageData)
    user["photo"] = imageFile -> [error in this line]


    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println("Signup Successful")

        }
        else {
            println("Signup Failed")
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it!

```
        user.setValue(imageFile, forKey:"photo")
```

it works now!!

Answer (score 1):

It means you cannot access the property `image` with a subscript. Instead of `user["photo"]` try user.photo

Comment: No, How is it possible.It says, 'PFUser' does not have a member named 'photo'. Because  user.email, user.password are already the members in the parse framework. user.photo cannot be defined because it is not a pre member or we call predefined.